# What's the equivalent of foldr, foldl in Emacs Lisp?

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

What's the equivalent of foldr, foldl in Emacs Lisp?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Since Emacs-24.3 we recommend the use of `cl-lib` over `cl` (which is planned for removal in some distant future), so it would be:

```
(require 'cl-lib)
(cl-reduce #'+ '(1 2 3 4))
```

and since Emacs-25, you can also use the `seq` package for that:

```
(require 'seq)
(seq-reduce #'+ '(1 2 3 4) 0)
```

Comment: This should better be a comment to Gareth Rees' answer than a separate answer in its own right.

Comment: @Thomas It is not possible to write multi line comments with examples on SO.

Comment: an initial value is required, for handling empty lists. e.g. `(seq-reduce #'list '(1 2 3 4) nil)` is `((((nil 1) 2) 3) 4)`. `(seq-reduce #'list (cdr '(1 2 3 4)) (car '(1 2 3 4)))` is `(((1 2) 3) 4)`.

Answer (score 30):

If you

```
(require 'cl)
```

then you can use the Common Lisp function [`reduce`](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/fun_reduce.html). Pass the keyword argument `:from-end t` for `foldr`.

```
ELISP> (reduce #'list '(1 2 3 4))
(((1 2) 3) 4)

ELISP> (reduce #'list '(1 2 3 4) :from-end t)
(1 (2 (3 4)))
```

Answer (score 9):

[Common Lisp library](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/) provides plenty of [sequence functions](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/Sequences.html#Sequences) like mapping, filtering, folding, searching and even sorting. CL library is shipped with Emacs by default, so you should stick to it. I however really like [`dash.el`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el) library, because it provides enormous amounts of functions for list and tree manipulations. It also supports [anaphoric macros](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaphoric_macro) and encourages functional programming, which makes code concise and elegant.

Haskell's folds correspond with `dash.el` folds:

- `foldl` with [`-reduce-from`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#-reduce-from-fn-initial-value-list)
- `foldr` with [`-reduce-r-from`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#-reduce-r-from-fn-initial-value-list)
- `foldl1` with [`-reduce`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#-reduce-fn-list)
- `foldr1` with [`-reduce-r`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#-reduce-r-fn-list)

Sum of a range 1 to 10 using folds might look like in this in Haskell and `dash.el`:

```
foldl (+) 0 [1..10] -- Haskell
(-reduce-from '+ 0 (number-sequence 1 10)) ; Elisp
```

You probably know, that folds are very general, and it is possible to implement maps and filters via folds. For example, to increment every element by 2, Haskell's currying and sections would allow for terse code, but in Elisp you would usually write verbose throwaway lambdas like that:

```
foldr ((:) . (+2)) [] [1..10] -- Haskell
(-reduce-r-from (lambda (x acc) (cons (+ x 2) acc)) '() (number-sequence 1 10)) ; Elisp
```

Guess what, it isn't necessary in `dash.el` with anaphoric macros, which allow special syntax by exposing variables of a lambda as shortcuts, like `it` and `acc` in folds. Anaphoric functions start with 2 dashes instead of 1:

```
(--reduce-r-from (cons (+ it 2) acc) '() (number-sequence 1 10))
```

There are plenty fold-like functions in `dash.el`:

```
;; Count elements matching a predicate
(-count 'evenp '(1 2 3 4 5)) ; 2
;; Add/multiply elements of a list together
(-sum '(1 2 3 4 5)) ; 15
(-product '(1 2 3 4 5)) ; 120
;; Find the smallest and largest element
(-min '(3 1 -1 2 4)) ; -1
(-max '(-10 0 10 5)) ; 10
;; Find smallest/largest with a custom rule (anaphoric versions)
(--min-by (> (length it) (length other)) '((1 2 3) (4 5) (6))) ; (6)
(--max-by (> (length it) (length other)) '((1 2 3) (4 5) (6))) ; (1 2 3)
```